# SQL check if date exists in the next 2 years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where each record has multiple dates saved in the date column such as Record ID '01' can have 6 rows with dates each from 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018 and 2019. Each record ID only has one date per year.

I am interested to see for all record ID that have a date in the current year, if they have a date in the next 2 years (i.e Record ID has a date from 2017 and 2018), just the next year (Record ID only has a date from 2017) or just this year.

I am not interested in records that do not have a date in the current year even if they may have dates in the next 2 years. I am also not interested in records that may have a date 3 years from now but not have a date in the next 2 years.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data along with the rows you do and do not want to see -- and why.  Your description is a bit hard to follow.  Also, how do you save six *dates* in one *column*.  That sounds like a very bad data format to me.  You should probably restructure your data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question. Try this.
**Updated.**

```
Select RecordID, Year(DateColumn)
From table
Where Year(DateColumn) Between Year(GetDate()) and (Year(GetDate()) + 2)    
Group By RecordID, Year(DateColumn)
Having Count(1) = 3
```

Comment: it's unclear how you expect any single row's `DateColumn` year to be simultaneously equal to three different values.

Comment: Agreed. After I posted it, I noticed that.